# Berries ID - Can someone help us identify this plant?

Tags: species-identification, botany

Found it in the hilly areas of Meghalaya - a state of India.

Not sure if is edible or not, we haven't tried it but it gives a beautiful blue color when used for dying.

The seeds are big and there is not enough fruit except its like the skin covering the seeds.[image: Wild berries]